# For-loop only working with specific values

Tags: javascript, html

I have 10 pictures(pic1.jpg, pic2.jpg, pic3.jpg...) and i am trying to make two input fields where i can input the last and first picture to be displayed. I have figured it out, but my loop only works for specific values. It will work when i input 1 and 10 or 5 and 9, but for instance 5 and 10 will not work. What am i doing wrong? My programming teacher could not figure it out either.

File Structure:

````
 
```
project
│   index.html
│   js-intro.js
│
└───pics
    │   pic1.jpg
    │   pic2.jpg
    |   ...
    |   pic10.jpg

```
````

HTML:

```
<b>First pic: </b> <input type="number" id="fromPic"> <br>
<b>Last pic: </b> <input type="number" id="toPic"> <br>
<button type="button" id="picButton">Show me!</button>
<div id="picDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
var fromPicEl = document.querySelector("#fromPic");
var toPicEl = document.querySelector("#toPic");
var picButtonEl = document.querySelector("#picButton");
var picDivEl = document.querySelector("#picDiv");
var fromPicValue;
var toPicValue;
function showPic() {
  picDivEl.innerHTML = "";
  fromPicValue = fromPicEl.value;
  toPicValue = toPicEl.value;
  while (fromPicValue<=toPicValue) {
    picDivEl.innerHTML += "<img src='pics/pic" + fromPicValue + ".jpg'>";
    fromPicValue++;
  }
}
picButtonEl.addEventListener("click", showPic);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you extract value from the input fields, they are of string format. You need to convert them to integers for correct comparison.
Change

```
fromPicValue = fromPicEl.value;
toPicValue = toPicEl.value;
```

to

```
fromPicValue = parseInt(fromPicEl.value);
toPicValue = parseInt(toPicEl.value);
```